# Scheduled Firebase Function - No writing to Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

My schedule Cloud Function is running on schedule, but not successfully writing to my Firestore instance. The code successfully writes to the FirestoreDB when I trigger it as an HTTP request locally. But it does not appear to be writing to Firestore once deployed with PubSub scheduling logic added.

The Function logs in GCP are showing a finished status of "ok".

Wondering if I'm doing something works in JS, but GCP or Pubsub doesn't like, even though it's technically valid JS?

Any help or direction is appreciated.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const request = require("request");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const serviceAccount = require("......");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.scheduledPRRfunction = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("every 2 minutes")
    .timeZone("America/New_York")
    .onRun(((context) => {
      const Options = {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "...",
        "headers": {
          "Cookie": ".....",
        },
      };

      db.collection("myCollectionName").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const documentIds = doc.id;
          // Delete Documents
          db.collection("myCollectionName")
              .doc(documentIds).delete().then(() => {
              }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error removing document: ", error);
              });
        });
      });

      // Write Documents
      request(Options, function(error, response) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        const apiResponse = JSON.parse(response.body);
        const parsedResponse = apiResponse["news_results"];
        for (let i = 0; i < parsedResponse.length; i++) {
          // console.log(i);
          db.collection("myCollectionName").add(parsedResponse[i]);
        }
      });
  }));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request` supports callback interfaces natively but does not return a promise, which is what you must do within a Pub/Sub Cloud Function (as well as within background Cloud Functions).

This is explained in the official Firebase video series here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/. In particular watch the three videos titled "Learn JavaScript Promises" (Parts 2 & 3 especially focus on background triggered Cloud Functions, but it really worth watching Part 1 before).

There is a [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise) library that could be used instead, but since Feb 11th 2020 `request` is fully deprecated, so I would recommend using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

The following code should do the trick (untested):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const axios = require('axios');

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.scheduledPRRfunction = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("every 2 minutes")
    .timeZone("America/New_York")
    .onRun(async (context) => {

        try {

            const querySnapshot = await db.collection("myCollectionName").get();
            const promises = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => db.collection("myCollectionName").doc(doc.id).delete());

            await Promise.all(promises);

            const options = {
                "method": "get",
                "url": "...",
                "headers": {
                    "Cookie": ".....",
                },
            };

            const axiosResponse = await axios(options);
            const apiResponse = JSON.parse(axiosResponse.data);
            const parsedResponse = apiResponse["news_results"];

            const docCreationPromises = parsedResponse.map(response => db.collection("myCollectionName").add(parsedResponse))

            await Promise.all(docCreationPromises);

            return null;

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        }

    });
```

Note that:

- We use [`async/await`](https://javascript.info/async-await), to make it easier to write the asynchronous code
- Since you are triggering several asynchronous operations in parallel you have to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

---

In addition, note that since Version 1.0.0 of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions, `firebase-admin` shall be initialized without any parameters within the Cloud Functions runtime, as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply @renaud_tarnec - I've updated my code using Axios and successfully deploy the scheduled function. Unfortunately it still is failing to write to my DB.

Comment: Can you debug? Do you get the correct result from the call to the API/URL? What is the value of `axiosResponse`? Also there was a typo at `db.collection("myCollectionName").add(parsedResponse)`: it was `db.collection("myCollectionName").add(response)`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @renaud-tarec. I'm having trouble running this function locally now.

`i  functions[us-central1-scheduledPRRfunction]: function ignored because the pubsub emulator does not exist or is not running.` I've confirmed that the PubSub emulator is running on Port 8085.

I'll work on getting this fixed and report back shortly.